# MongoServerError: Found multiple array filters with the same top-level field name

Tags: mongoose

I'm getting `MongoServerError: Found multiple array filters with the same top-level field name atten` and I'm not sure what is wrong? Thanks

Here is the schema:

```
const attendanceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    courseTitle: { type: String, trim: true },
    enrollment: [{
        studentName: { type: String, trim: true},
        attendanceTaking: [{
            datenumber:{type:Number},
            attendanceDate: { type: Date}
        }],
    }],
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Here is the findOneAndUpdate:

```
 await Attendance.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:{ "$eq": sanitize(req.body.courseData._id)}},
        {
          $push: {
            "enrollment.$[enroll].attendanceTaking.$[atten].datenumber": datenumber,
            "enrollment.$[enroll].attendanceTaking.$[atten].attendanceDate": new Date()
          }
        },
        { arrayFilters: [{ 'enroll.studentName': "John Doe"},{'atten.datenumber': {"$exists": false }}, {'atten.attendanceDate': {"$exists": false}} ], new: true }
        )

        return res.json({ statusCode: "200", msg: 'ok' });
```

I have some changes to the findOneAndUpdate to the ArrayFilter section of the code above:

```
{ arrayFilters: [{ 'enroll.studentName': "John Doe"},{'atten.datenumber': {"$exists": false }, 'atten.attendanceDate': {"$exists": false}} ], new: true }
```

It shows no error now but it is not updating. Wondering where is wrong? Thanks